# Pass data between objects in python

Tags: python, class, pass-by-reference

I'm new to python and I'm not sure how to pass data between objects. Below is a tabbed program using python and wxwidgets. How would I be able to access the maintxt instance from the GetText method since their in different classes?

Thanks.

........

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx


class PageText(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.maintxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(0, 40), size=(850,320))

        self.Show(True)


class PageList(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.bPutText = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Put Text', pos=(855, 40), size=(75, 30))
        self.bPutText.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.GetText)


    def GetText(self, event):
        # Write text into maintxt


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="ADMIN")

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        vPageText = PageText(nb)
        vPageList = PageList(nb)

        nb.AddPage(vPageText, "Edit Text")
        nb.AddPage(vPageList, "Book List")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You never pass data between classes.  You pass data -- objects -- among objects.  It's all objects.  What data object and what GUI objects are you trying to work with?  Please **update** your question to identify the object instances, not the classes.

Comment: I actually did mention it was the maintxt instance in my post. I've removed the word classes from the title in case you were confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might be mixing logic with presentation.  You should perhaps have a network of model classes that describe the behaviors of your domain (pages?) and then pass instances of those classes to the initializers of your presentation classes, so they know which models they are representing.

More about this design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller